# Integrate OpenAM 12.0.0 and Liferay 6.2

Tags: liferay, openam

I want to use OpenAM 12.0.0 for authentication with Liferay 6.2 but I could not find any documentation on how to do that? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

https://wikis.forgerock.org/confluence/display/openam/integrate+OpenAM+with+Liferay

http://www.kianworknotes.com/2013/02/how-to-integrate-openam-with-liferay.html

Hope this helps and get to moving. Cheers! :)